# passing arguments to contract file in solidity, when I tried to test the contract it returns 0

Tags: blockchain, solidity, truffle, metamask, ganache

I passed the totalSupply in 2_deploy_contract.js

```
const HelioToken = artifacts.require("HelioToken");
module.exports = function (deployer) {
  const intialSupply = 1000000;
  deployer.deploy(HelioToken,intialSupply);
};
```

this is my contract HelioToke.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract HelioToken {
        // constructor
        // set the total number of token 
        // read the total number of token

        uint256 public totalSupply;
        mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

        constructor(uint256 _initialSupply) {
                balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
                totalSupply = _initialSupply;
        }
        
}
```

I tried this code in truffle console

```
truffle(development)> HelioToken.deployed().then(function(i){token=i;})
undefined
truffle(development)> token.totalSupply().then(function(s){supply=s;})
undefined
truffle(development)> supply
BN { negative: 0, words: [ 0, <1 empty item> ], length: 1, red: null }
truffle(development)> supply.toNumber()
0
truffle(development)>
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. I deployed your contract on Remix and got this error

```
 Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the 
       value you send should be less than your current balance.
```

I marked constructor as `payable` then it deployed

```
    constructor(uint256 _initialSupply) payable {
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
            totalSupply = _initialSupply;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, you are correct my code is correct I tried in the test.js file it was working fine.

I'm using ganache

Comment: Are you able to use the contract inside test.js without `payable` signature on constructor

Comment: Yes, I run this without ```payable```